# javac command line `-Akey[=value]` args are not covered via javac plugins, only annotation processors. How best to address this?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Although the javac docs state the `-Akey[=value]` command line argument is designed for annotation processors, it applies to javac plugins as well; there doesn't appear to be a separate command line argument exclusive to plugins.

The problem, however, is that internally javac emits a warning if a `-Akey` is not acknowledged by an annotation processor. Of course plugins can still process the arguments, but the warning confuses devs.

I'd like to report a bug/request to perhaps allow plugins to acknowledge `-Akey` command line options. But [openjdk.org](https://openjdk.org) is in reality a pretty closed system, I'm just a dude without "project author" privileges necessary to report a bug. Is there some other way to submit an issue?

Admittedly, plugins are one of javac's darker corners, but I'm curious if anyone else has run into this and how they may have addressed it. I am currently suppressing the error via compiler internals, which of course isn't a desirable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I had forgotten about arguments that can be passed to plugins via the [init](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/util/Plugin.html#init(com.sun.source.util.JavacTask,java.lang.String...)) method. I had switched from building an annotation processor to a plugin, but chose to stick with the `-A` style of argument passing for a couple of reasons.

1. it was an easier transition for existing usage
2. I prefer adding arguments to the javac command line as opposed to my plugin having separate arguments

I'd still like to file a request to allow plugins to acknowledge `-Akey` args, if there is some way to achieve that.